# AngularJS single item update with button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Okay so I have a products array in Firebase

```
products
 -JpzIlrpRfXzx5HbZMw_
    description: 'The description to the product'
    image: 'The link to the product image'
    likes: '0' 
    price: '15'
    title: 'The product title
```

And i'm wanting to add a "like" button to each product. It needs to increment the like above by one each time the button is clicked.

I have figured out how to do it with an input where you type the like but that isn't very friendly.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="product.likes" ng-change="products.$save(product)"/>
```

How would I go about changing the input to a button? That when clicked increments the products like integer by 1.

Comment: You need to use a [transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions) to increment your counter or concurrent edits are going to be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function just increment `product.likes` by one and post your product object back to your db

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdg7yho/4/)

```
<button type="button" ng-click="products.$save(product)">Save </button>
<p>{{product.likes}}</p>
```

JS:

```
$scope.products = {
      $save : function(product) {
          product.likes += 1;
          //post your product
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty straight-forward:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="product.likes += 1; products.$save(product);"/>
```

**Note:** I would suggest you to extract it into a function

Comment: This results in a syntax error? https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=